# Pagination does not work where page address changed using mod rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, pagination

The code below is part of pagination code this code works well in ordinary case but where address of page has been changed using mod Rewrite pagination does not works it loads page 2 but with same data.

```
// The "back" link
$prevlink = ($page > 1) ? '<a href="?page=1" title="First page" >&laquo;</a> <a href="?page=' . ($page - 1) . '" title="Previous page" >&lsaquo;</a>' : '<span class="disabled">&laquo;</span> <span class="disabled">&lsaquo;</span>';
// The "forward" link
$nextlink = ($page < $pages) ? '<a href="?page=' . ($page + 1) . '" title="Next page">&rsaquo;</a> <a href="?page=' . $pages . '" title="Last page">&raquo;</a>' : '<span class="disabled">&rsaquo;</span> <span class="disabled">&raquo;</span>';
```

For example I am having a page `test.com/profile.php` which I am changing to `test.com/username` this is done by:

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?username=$1
```

Now here pagination works for `test.com/profile.php` but does not work for `test.com/username` How to make pagination work in second case?

Comment: you're stripping off the pagination query string values when you do your username rewrite. if you want pagination on user pages, then you have to pass those pagination values through... That or use the [QSA] option for mod_rewrite so it appends any query values to the new url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add QSA flag to transfer the current query string

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?username=$1 [QSA] 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?username=$1 [QSA]
```

> https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteFlags/QSA